# Semantic UI and flask

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to use semantic UI within my flask application template code and trying to display a text area as follows:

```
<div class="ui container">
        <div class="html ui top attached segment" style="margin: 5px auto 0;">
            <div class="ui top attached green massive label">Please paste text in the box below</div>
            <div class="ui form" id="inputForm" method="post">
                <div class="field">
                    <textarea placeholder="Feel free to use free-text to input the patient phenotype description" id="note" name="content">{{request.form['content']}}></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is that it seems to be having trouble with the `{{request.form['content']}}` placeholder. Without that bit, the placeholder text appears fine otherwise it gets replaced with a single `>` as shown in the attached screenshot.

Is there something special that needs to change for this to work? Ia m new to web development in general.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured it out. A silly error. Needed to be:

```
<textarea placeholder="Feel free to use free-text to input the patient phenotype description" id="note" name="content" value="{{request.form['content']}}"></textarea>
```